# shopify textmade bundle Upload Error

Tags: textmate, shopify

I have succesfully downloaded the full theme from my shopify store but i am unable to upload any changes. WHen i try to upload I get the following error:

xattr: /Users/**/desktop/shopify_store/layout/theme.liquid no such xattr: id error... try again

I am using Mac OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The first result](http://www.google.com/search?q=shopify%20error%20upload%20xattr) in google is [a discussion involving the bundle's author](http://forums.shopify.com/categories/1/posts/48132) on the Shopify forum. I think you'll get better help over there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I'll echo that sentiment. best place is the forum, or github issues for the project.

That being said, in this case, you are most likely in HTML language mode, and you need to be in liquid mode. Pages and assets are different.